# Code works ONLY if there is a cout following a cin - C++

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I am running the below c++ code. I am reading in an int first, and then an array of numbers(which is done in the first for loop).

After reading in each value for the array, the array is properly stored only if that cout line is in the for loop(marked with **** in the code)

I don't understand what the issue is.

Please let me know if I am forgetting something...

Also: this is what the input looks like:

```
8
1 1 2 2 6 9 9 15
4
1
4
9
15
```

Output displays a bunch of newlines and then the expected output. Below is sample

```
//8 empty lines(because of the cout << endl, omitted for lack of space
Yes 1
No 5
Yes 6
Yes 8
```

Thanks.

```
    int main() {
    int len, nQueries; 
    int arr[len]; 
    cin >> len; // first value read in

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int val, junk; 
        cin >> val; 
        arr[i] = val;  
        cout << endl; // if this is removed, array is not fully read in. **********
    }
    cin >> nQueries;     

    for(int k = 0; k < nQueries; k++)
    {
        int query; 
        bool found = false; 
        cin >> query; 
        for(int j = 0; j<len; j++)
        {
            if((arr[j]==query)&&(found == false))
            {
                cout << "Yes " << j + 1 << endl; 
                found = true; 
            }

            if(arr[j]>query && found==false)
            {
                cout << "No " << j+1 << endl; 
                found = true; 
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @sye The program has undefined behavior because the variable  len is not initialized    int len, nQueries; 
    int arr[len];  And variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I see that mistake *constantly*. Is there some other language you've seen that actually supports that? I mean, that *specific* workflow of `var[len]`, then later changing *just* `len`, and the array automagically resizes? Just curious if there is some common thread besides poor instruction that leads to that assumption by language newcomers.

Comment: I stumbled across one, once. You declared all of the variables and formulas ahead of time and the runtime applied the formulas as the variables received input . Can't remember the name, but I don't think it made it out of academia.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow so is this fixed by simply moving the array declaration until after reading in the initial value of `len`?

Comment: Oh wow, I did not realize that I was creating the array before reading in len. I switched it around and it seems to work! Thank you so much for your help!!!